# Spring Roo 2 : 404 when running the sample web app

Tags: spring-roo

I've downloaded Spring Roo 2.0.0 RC1 along with Spring Tools Suite 3.9 on OS X.

I created an empty project then run the following command to import the PetClinic sample :

```
script --file clinic.roo
```

The import as well as the Maven dependencies install worked as expected.
But when I run the application on the server (stock Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2), I get a 404 error !

I put a debug breakpoint on the annotated `@SpringBootApplication` main class in which we have the main and nothing caught.

Question : how can I run the pet clinic sample ? Why the application doesn't boot ?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) : In order to start it correctly on a Java EE server, you have to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Please, make sure that this class comes from the `org.springframework.boot.web.support` package and **not** from the `org.springframework.boot.context.web` package.

After the `extends` you have to override the `configure` method just like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PetClinicApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    private static Class<PetClinicApplication> applicationClass = PetClinicApplication.class;

    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PetClinicApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }
}
```

Explanation (from the same link above):

> This new base class - SpringBootServletInitializer - taps into a Servlet 3 style Java configuration API which lets you describe in code what you could only describe in web.xml before.